# Getting a single AngularFirestoreDocument from a AngularFirestoreCollection query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angularfire5

In Firestore, I have a `uid` as a field in my `Vendor` documents:

```
/vendors
    +doc1
        uid: 1
    +doc2
        uid: 2
```

To access the vendors, I'm using the following function:

```
getVendor(index: string): AngularFirestoreDocument<Vendor> {
    return afs.doc<Vendor>(`vendors/${index}`);
}
```

I'd like to create a similar function, which also returns an `AngularFirestoreDocument`, but the function takes a `uid` to get the document:

```
getVendorByUID(uid: string): AngularFirestoreDocument<Vendor> {

    ...

    return theDoc;
}
```

It seems like I have to query an AngularFirestoreCollection, but don't know how to extract the Document from the Collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the uid as the key for the record; that way you can just reference it by URL w/`getVendor`

Otherwise you need to query:

```
// Query the first vendor where the uid matches
afs.collection<Vendor>(`vendors`, ref => ref.where('uid', '==', uid).limit(1))
  .valueChanges()
  .pipe(
    map(vendors => vendors[0]) // flatten the result
  );
```